# Is the Tongue a Melee Weapon?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 there are several (similar) creatures that attack by licking you, attaching their tongue and leaping toward you.  I hate these guys; not only do they deal large amounts of damage, but they seem to always target me and not my minions. (Furthermore being licked to death is unsettling.)

The question is, do these licks count as melee attacks, or ranged attacks for purposes of armor (skills?) that reduce incoming melee OR ranged attack damage?

Comment: ... and in the game!

Comment: I'd say "get more armor/resistances", but it wouldn't answer your question. But anyway, get more armor/resistances!

Comment: Oh, I survive @Novarg, but the sheer embarrassment makes me wish I had died!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5889900438) on the diablo 3 forums, a little old but I doubt anything changed since, here are some attacks that are considered melee, including the soul leasher/ripper :

> YES *Fallen Maniac suicide bomb
>
> **YES *Soul lasher/ripper tongue attack**
>
> NO *Herald of Pestilence poison pool attack
>
> NO *The fire breath from an Oppressor but each charging hit from oppressor counts as TWO melees.
>
> NO *Ghom spitting acid on you when you are close range. but
>
> YES on Ghom biting you
>
> YES *Belial's arm smash (phase 3)
>
> YES *Belial's exploding green circles
>
> YES *All of Belial's phase 3 attacks are melee.
>
> NO *The DOT when Diablo grabs you
>
> NO *"Desecrator" circles
>
> NO *"Plagued" circles
>
> NO *"Molten" lava path
>
> YES *The explosion after molten elites die
>
> New discoveries:
>
> YES *Siegebreaker charging attack
>
> NO *Siegebreaker grab and throw attack and some stabbing attacks
>
> YES *Explosion traps (like the ones in Siegebreaker and Arreat crater)
>
> YES *Arcane lasers YES *Fire spewing structures (in Arreat crater)
>
> NO*Fire chains

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Now I finally know that my real life tongue-based arsenal is full of melee weapons.